# Получить значение из Combobox, который внутри DataGrid WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть `DataGrid`, в ней несколько колонок, одна из них с `Combobox`. Список для `Combobox` подгружаю из внешнего файла. Все отображается, но никак не получается получить значение выбранного значения у Combobox. Как правильно это можно сделать. Стараюсь использовать MVVM. 
Вот мой `DataGrid`

```
        <DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ParametersCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectFile2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Имя" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding GroupString}" Header="Группа" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Тип" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding DeleteCheckBox}" Header="Удаление" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding MigrateValueCheckBox}" Header="Перенос значения"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Замена" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FopParameterCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding }"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Категории">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..." 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CategoryCount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Свойство ParametersCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<Parameter> ParametersCollection
{
get => _ParametersCollection;
set
{
_ParametersCollection = value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ParametersCollection));
}
}
```

Класс Parameter

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string GroupString { get; set; }
    public BuiltInParameterGroup BuiltInParameterGroup { get; set; }
    public ParameterType Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> EnumCategory { get; set; }
    public bool DeleteCheckBox { get; set; }
    public bool MigrateValueCheckBox { get; set; }
    public Parameter GetFopParameter { get; set; }
    public string CountCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> FileCategoriesList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: А в чем смысл выносить `FopParameterCollection` за пределы объекта основной коллекции? Ну а по сабжу, то вы же сделали привязку самой коллекции к комбобоксу, делайте также привязку и выбранного объекта.

Comment: Я подгружаю его из другого источника, из файла txt. Или я вас не правильно понял? Да, у меня там не привязано, но я пытаюсь по разному делать, но пока не получается. Как я понимаю, мне нужно выбранное значение привязать к свойству`GetFopParameter `, но оно не доступно, я не могу к нему привязаться

Comment: Просто понимаете, по всяким правилам например ООП, у вас должен быть объект, который отвечает за что то свое, одно. Если этому объекту нежно как то взаимодействовать с другим объектом, то внутрь передается например ссылка, с помощью которой он имеет доступ. По этому принципу и построено все WPF. Он привязывает контрол к коллекции, которая имеет один объект, который и отобразиться, один.

Comment: У вас же все намешано как по мне в одну кучу и если так посмотреть на код, то для работы класса `Parameter` он должен знать о `FopParameterCollection`, причем у каждого `Parameter` может быть свой `FopParameterCollection` (как я понял, что то по типу некого выбранного статуса). Так может вам и стоит сделать так, что бы `Parameter` сам отвечал за вывод этих `FopParameterCollection`? Загрузите эту коллекцию где то за пределами класса (если она одна и грузится из вне) и передавайте ее ссылкой в класс `Parameter` и к этой ссылке и привязывайте тогда. Это если я конечно правильно понял задачу...

Comment: Да, я понял про что вы, я исправил, добавил еще одно свойство в класс параметр, куда передаю подгруженный список, но пока все никак не получается отобразить этот спиcок. пытаюсь сделать немного по другому, в   `<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource=""/>`   подать то свойство, но оно что то не видно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге у меня получилось следующим образом

```
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Заменить на" Width="*" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding GetFopParameter}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                            Path=DataContext.FopParameterCollection_MV, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                            Path=DataContext.FopParameterCollection_MV, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```